# Scala FOLD executing both invalid and valid blocks of code

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, validation, playframework

I have the following code where I am validating a JSON input via a controller. I am using JSON schema validation and providing responses based on if it's valid or invalid as you can see in the code. I get the following weird behavior  when I am sending an invalid JSON.

```
[error] - superman - Event=Bad Request Received, Reason=Invalid Json, Response={"GUID":"\"e28fa115-67f4-4265-b7d0-61e6af1237c2\"","status":"error","description":"Invalid Request Received","violations":"List(\"Property action missing\")"}
invalid
successfully inserted document with result = DefaultWriteResult(true,1,List(),None,None,None)
```

Why is it running the line of code from the valid block `mongo.writeDocument(reqJson)` while the JSON is invalid and it actually prints `invalid` from the invalid block. However, another thing to note is that it does *not* print the `valid` string even though its right next to the `mongo.writeDocument(reqJson)`

```
def validateJson = Action(parse.json) {

    request => {
      val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("superman")
      val jsonSchema = Source.fromFile(play.api.Play.getFile("conf/schema.json")).getLines.mkString
      val reqJson: JsValue = request.body
      val GUID = (reqJson \ "guid").get
      val result: VA[JsValue] = SchemaValidator.validate(Json.fromJson[SchemaType](
        Json.parse(jsonSchema.stripMargin)).get, reqJson)

      result.fold(
        invalid = { errors =>

          var violatesList = List[String]()
          var invalidError = Map("GUID" -> GUID.toString(), "status" -> "error", "description" -> "Invalid Request Received")
          for (msg <- (errors.toJson \\ "msgs"))
            violatesList = (msg(0).get).toString() :: violatesList
          invalidError += ("violations" -> (violatesList.toString()))
          val errorResponse = Json.toJson(invalidError)
          logger.error("Event=Bad Request Received, Reason=Invalid Json, Response=" + errorResponse)
          println("invalid")
          BadRequest(errorResponse)

        },

        valid = {
          println("valid")
          mongo.writeDocument(reqJson)
          val successResponse = Json.obj("GUID" -> GUID.toString, "status" -> "OK", "message" -> ("Valid Request Received"))
          logger.info("Event=Valid Request Received, Response=" + successResponse)
          post => Ok(successResponse)
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: are you sure the valid corresponds to the "invalid" object? I will add more data to that line, println("valid " + reqJson) and same for invalid println("invalid " + reqJson), println I imagine goes to stdoutput and logger as well but nothing prevents from mixing in different order since logger more likely is an actor in play

Comment: I added the extra println stuff and now its printing valid + reqJson, error from BADRequest, invalid + reqJson and also writing to the mongoDB => all while I am sending an invalid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking a few more docs, I found that `post =>` should be right next to `valid = {` function like this :

```
valid = {
          post =>
          println("valid")
          mongo.writeDocument(reqJson)
          val successResponse = Json.obj("GUID" -> GUID.toString, "status" -> "OK", "message" -> ("Valid Request Received"))
          logger.info("Event=Valid Request Received, Response=" + successResponse)
          Ok(successResponse)
        }
```